# How to setup zsh/ohmyzsh in nixos?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, nix

my nixos config looks like this:

```
{ config, pkgs, ... }: {
  programs.zsh = {
    enable = true;
    ohMyZsh = {
        enable = true;
        plugins = [ "git" "zsh-history-substring-search" ];
    };    
  };
  users.users.USER.shell = pkgs.zsh;
  environment.systemPackages = [
    pkgs.oh-my-zsh
    pkgs.zsh
    pkgs.zsh-completions
    pkgs.zsh-powerlevel10k
    pkgs.zsh-syntax-highlighting
    pkgs.zsh-history-substring-search
  ];
}
```

and i kind of expected that my existing .zshrc just works, but this is not the case. For example when opening a new shell i get this error:

```
[oh-my-zsh] plugin 'zsh-history-substring-search' not found
```

But its clearly installed (see systemPackages).

Also i had this in my .zshrc file:

```
source /usr/share/zsh-theme-powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme
```

which makes sense that it cannot be sourced (since its probably installed somewhere else), but my question now is: where is stuff actually installed in nixos? How can i find this file?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be installing any of this as system packages _at all_, but would be using home-manager or similar.

Comment: what is the difference between homemanager and systempackages? I looked into homemanager, but it looks like just another package manager ontop, so i think that using a single package manager is better then splitting it over multiple ones

Comment: The point of home-manager and similar is that you're letting users configure their own environments, not making decisions for _all_ your users as part of the configuration of your system. system-packages go in `/run/current-system/sw` shared by everyone and require someone with root to change, whereas a user's own `~/.nix-profile` is changed whenever that user wants without requiring them to have root; it's thus more parsimoneous for a sysadmin to make decisions only for the whole system and leave decisions about user accounts to the users.

Comment: iam setting up my own VM, iam the only user and will always be the only user on that system, so i personally dont see homemanager as really being that useful, since it introduces another layer of (different) configuration

Comment: _nod_, if you're the only user then the argument I applied doesn't really make sense. Anyhow, in terms of where things go -- look at the `/run/current-system/sw` symlink tree; you'll see anything in system-packages under there.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks correct. Here are some debugging ideas,

1. Check where ohmyzsh is installed. Your `zshrc` should have a line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` generated. Run `cd $ZSH` to enter that directory.
2. Inspect the `oh-my-zsh.sh` file. There should be a block similar to the one below (I use home-manager, so yours might look different)

```
# Add all defined plugins to fpath. This must be done
# before running compinit.
for plugin ($plugins); do
  if is_plugin "$ZSH_CUSTOM" "$plugin"; then
    fpath=("$ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/$plugin" $fpath)
  elif is_plugin "$ZSH" "$plugin"; then
    fpath=("$ZSH/plugins/$plugin" $fpath)
  else
    echo "[oh-my-zsh] plugin '$plugin' not found"
  fi
done
```

Here you can find the plugins directory. In my case it was `plugins` folder in the same directory.

3. Check if the plugins are present in that folder

fyi,

- You can also enable syntax highlighting by setting `programs.zsh.syntaxHighlighting.enable` to true
- You can set the theme using `programs.zsh.ohMyZsh.theme` instead of sourcing the theme file manually.